# Android - NotificationCompat.Builder stacking notifications with setGroup(group) not working

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to stack notifications using setGroup (as described here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html)
Basically, I use 0 as notification id (always the same) and `builder.setGroup("test_group_key")` but a new notification always replaces the previous one.
What could be the problem ?

Code:

```
public BasicNotifier(Context context) {
    super(context);
    notifManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setSound(alarmSound)
        .setAutoCancel(true);

    stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(getParentActivityClass());

}

public void showNotification(String title, String text, Intent intent, Class cls) {
    if (text.length() > 190)
        text = text.substring(0, 189) + "...";

    mBuilder.setTicker(text).setContentText(text).setContentTitle(title);

    Intent notificationIntent = intent == null ? new Intent() : new Intent(intent);
    notificationIntent.setClass(getContext(), cls);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setGroup("test_group_key");

    Notification notif = mBuilder.build();
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notifManager.notify(replaceOnNew ? 0 : nextId++, notif); // replaceOnNew
                                                                // is "true"

    Log.i(TAG, "Notification shown: " + nextId + " = " + title);
}
```

EDIT:

It seams there is a problem when using NotificationManagerCompat, the notifications are not being displayed at all.

```
  NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext());
  notificationManager.notify(id, notif);
```

Comment: Did you find an answer? And can you show the new code?

Comment: For anyone else coming across this issue, there seems to be a bug in the support library across several versions https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159947

Answer (score 4):

You don't use notification id correctly.

"To set up a notification so it can be updated, issue it with a notification ID by calling NotificationManager.notify(ID, notification). To update this notification once you've issued it, update or create a NotificationCompat.Builder object, build a Notification object from it, and issue the Notification with the same ID you used previously."

[from Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html)

So in your case, if you want to stack notification in your group, you need to specify a new id for each new notification.

Comment: That is what I thought to. So I tried to increment (notifId++) but then all my notifications are shown independently, with no grouping.

Comment: On your [link](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html) it's said you need to have differents id, see the first part:

for the first one:
notificationManager.notify(notificationId1, notif);
and the second one:
notificationManager.notify(notificationId2, notif2);

Where do you save, the notifId ? are you sure the notifId are different ?

Comment: I use the same object BasicNotifier for all my notifications and I tested with "notifManager.notify(nextId++, notif)" (equivalent to replaceOnNew=false in my posted code). "nextId" is a field in by BasicNotifier class.

Comment: I've tested with NotificationManagerCompat and it did't work well. I switched to notifManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) and NotificationCompat.InboxStyle() to display stacked notifications on multiple lines. I use a notification id for each logical group, and I keep a list of the last 5 notification texts to add them as lines to InboxStyle.